# Failing to check if time is in the past using strtotime

Tags: php

I am trying to check if a certain time is in the past. Solution 1 works but the solutions 2 and 3 using strtotime do not. Any ideas why the strtotime solutions fail with this date when they work fine when the date is not that distant (f.ex. using 27.05.2035 works)?

```
  <?php
$date = "27.05.2045";
$hour = "22";
$min = "15";

// 1. This one works
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y H:i', $date.' '.$hour.':'.$min);
$now = new DateTime();
  if ($datetime < $now)
{
echo "Datetime is in the past";
}

else if ($datetime > $now)
{
echo "Datetime is in the future";
}

// 2. Does not work
  if (time() > strtotime($date.' '.$hour.':'.$min))
{
echo "Datetime is in the past (strtotime)";
}
else if (time() < strtotime($date.' '.$hour.':'.$min))
{
echo "Datetime is in the future (strtotime)";
}    

// 3. Using another date format but still does not work
$array  = explode('.', $date);
$date_converted = $array[2].'-'.$array[1].'-'.$array[0];

  if (time() > strtotime($date_converted.' '.$hour.':'.$min))
{
echo "Datetime is in the past (strtotime with converted date)";
}
else if (time() < strtotime($date_converted.' '.$hour.':'.$min))
{
echo "Datetime is in the future (strtotime with converted date)";
}    

?>
```

Comment: Are you on a 32bit PHP install? if so, then you cannot use dates past early 2038. That's when the internal signed 32bit integer used for time values will overflow and wrap back to 1901.

Comment: That seems to be the problem. Thanks a million!

Comment: So now, what's going to happen "after" year 2038? Kind of like "oh sure, 64k will be enough (B.G.)", or "the millenium bug". Doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Unix timestamps are basically the number of seconds passed since 1970-01-01, there's a maximum integer value. That value in 32-bit (2^32 - 1) seconds since 1970, is 2038-01-19.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Thank you. So what will happen after that, and will there be a solution?

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Well, what happens normally with max integer overflows, they warp back to their negative values. (Try it and see :)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I would if I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 32 bit integer maximum makes it impossible to represent dates past 19 January 2038.

The solution would be to either:

1. Use `DateTime` objects, which do not represent dates using the number of seconds passed since 1970, but using a field for each time unit.
2. Use the 64-bit version of PHP, where the maximum integer is much higher.

See **[The 2038 Year Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)** for more details.